# Problema com Data Base SQLite Android

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sql-update

Então galera meu problema é esse ai, já tentei e pesquisei de tudo mas não consegui implementar nenhuma solução. Tentei atualizar o banco com o update e também inserir novas colunas com o ALTER TABLE, nada deu certo. Sou iniciante então peço que por favor sejam bem específicos com as respostas. Obrigado.

```
Nome has no column named bairro (code 1): ,while compiling:
INSERT INTO Nome(email,bairro,rua,nomeDoCliente,telefoneResidencial,celular) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

```
//Create da classe Helper
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
            + ClientesDAO.TABLE_NAME
            + " (" + ClientesDAO.ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + ClientesDAO.NOME_CLIENTE + " TEXT,"
            + ClientesDAO.RUA + " TEXT,"
            + ClientesDAO.EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + ClientesDAO.BAIRRO + " TEXT,"
            + ClientesDAO.TELEFONE + " TEXT,"
            + ClientesDAO.CELULAR + " TEXT);"
);


//insert da classe ClientesDAO
public void insert(Clientes clientes){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NOME_CLIENTE, clientes.getNome());
    cv.put(RUA, clientes.getRua());
    cv.put(BAIRRO, clientes.getBairro());
    cv.put(EMAIL, clientes.getEmail());
    cv.put(TELEFONE, clientes.getTelefone());
    cv.put(CELULAR, clientes.getCelular());

    db.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}


//Método setado no onClick da minha tela de cadastros
public void gravarNoBanco(){
    cd.insert(new Clientes(0, edit_nome.getText().toString(),edit_rua.getText().toString(),edit_email.getText().toString(),edit_bairro.getText().toString(),edit_telefone.getText().toString(),edit_celular.getText().toString()));
    clear();
}
```

Comment: Sempre que alterar o banco de dados tem de desinstalar a aplicação **ou** incrementar a sua versão na classe que herda de *SQLiteOpenHelper*

Comment: Resolvido era isso mesmo.obg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que me parece, a [resposta de **sachin garg**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442348/1639385) para uma [pergunta semelhante em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441927/android-sqlite-issue-table-has-no-column-named) pode resolver o seu problema também:

> Parece que você adicionou algumas colunas posteriormente no banco de dados. Você deve considerar desinstalar e reinstalar seu aplicativo. Uma melhor abordagem é excluir (drop) e recriar todas as tabelas no método `onUpdate`, e incrementar a versão do banco de dados todas as vezes que você modificar o esquema.

Comment: Perfeito, era esse o problema, obg.

Answer (score 0):

Aumente a versão de seu banco de dados e implemente o seguinte método

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //codigo para atualizar suas tabelas, alter table por exemplo
    }
```

Sempre que a versão do banco de dados for aumentada, o método onUpgrade será chamado na primeira vez que a conexão com o banco for instanciada após o aumento de versão